# Magento 2.3 - Login Authentication not working for validating customer email and password

Tags: magento2.3, customer, customer-account, rest-api, customer-login

Hi I have created Rest API for customer login with custom module for my Magento 2.3 store.

I am entering parameters `email` and `password` for customer login. But it throws InvalidEmailOrPasswordException while firing api request.

Below is my code:

```
<?php
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;

class CustomerManagement
{

    /**
     * @var Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface
     */
    protected $accountManagementInterface;
    protected $customer;
    protected $_customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        AccountManagementInterface $accountManagementInterface,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {

        $this->objectManager = $context->getObjectManager();
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->accountManagementInterface = $accountManagementInterface;
        $this->customer = $customer;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


public function getLogin()
{
    $email = $this->request->getParam('email');
    $password = $this->request->getParam('password');

    try {
        /* @var $customer \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface */
        $customer = $this->accountManagementInterface->authenticate($email, $password);
        $websiteId = $customer->getWebsiteId();

        /* @var $_customer \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer */
        $_customer = $this->customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);

        $this->_customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($_customer->loadByEmail($email));   

    } catch(\Magento\Framework\Exception\InvalidEmailOrPasswordException $ex) {
        $errorData[0]['code'] = 7;
        $errorData[0]['message'] = 'Invalid Params!';
        $errorData[0]['exception'] = $ex;
        return $errorData;
    }
    .....
}
```

Here my code throws catch exception even if I use valid email and password for customer login API.

Answer (score 0):

Following code is wrong:

> ```
>     $customer = $this->accountManagementInterface->authenticate($newLoginValue, $password);
> ```

Should be:

```
    $customer = $this->accountManagementInterface->authenticate($email, $password);
```

Answer (score 0):

Email ID is missing. Update function as:

```
public function getLogin()
{
    $email = $this->request->getParam('email');
    $password = $this->request->getParam('password');

    try {
        /* @var $customer \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface */
        $customer = $this->accountManagementInterface->authenticate($email, $password);
        $websiteId = $customer->getWebsiteId();

        /* @var $_customer \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer */
        $_customer = $this->customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);

        $this->_customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($_customer->loadByEmail($email));   

    } catch(\Magento\Framework\Exception\InvalidEmailOrPasswordException $ex) {
        $errorData[0]['code'] = 7;
        $errorData[0]['message'] = 'Invalid Params!';
        $errorData[0]['exception'] = $ex;
        return $errorData;
    }
    .....
}
```